# MATLAB neural network for image recognition does not work

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to get familiar with the Image category classification using deep learning. I am trying to run the Matlab example available on

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-deep-learning.html

However running this example is giving me the following error

```
Error using message/getString
Unable to load a message catalog 'nnet_cnn:layer:Layer'. Please check
the file location and format.

Error in nnet.cnn.layer.Layer/getVectorHeader (line 113)
            header = getString( message( ...

Error in nnet.cnn.layer.Layer/displayNonScalarObject (line 86)
                header = sprintf( '  %s\n', getVectorHeader( layers )
                );

Error in cnn (line 150)
convnet.Layers
```

Moreover if I pass and ignore this error, I will get the following error later for the line

`trainingFeatures = activations(convnet, trainingSet, featureLayer, ...
'MiniBatchSize', 32, 'OutputAs', 'columns')`

```
Undefined variable "nnet" or class "nnet.internal.cnngpu.convolveForward2D".

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.layer.Convolution2D/doForward (line 218)
            Z = nnet.internal.cnngpu.convolveForward2D( ...

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.layer.Convolution2D/forwardNormal (line 195)
            Z = this.doForward(X,this.Weights.Value,this.Bias.Value);

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.layer.Convolution2D/forward (line 98)
                [Z, memory] = this.forwardNormal( X );

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.SeriesNetwork/activations (line 50)
                output = this.Layers{currentLayer}.forward( output );

Error in SeriesNetwork/activations (line 269)
                YChannelFormat = predictNetwork.activations(X, layerID);

Error in cnn (line 262)
trainingFeatures = activations(convnet, trainingSet, featureLayer, ...
```

Can please someone tell me the possibilities for getting this error and how to solve it.

Regards